# How to create a timer task which can be cancelled and rescheduled

Tags: java, time, timer

I have an application which needs to be run every nth minute of an hour n can be 5 , 15 , 30 etc...
So I wrote a timer which will be called every 1 minute and I will do current time in minutes % n to check if its time to schedule.

Now problem is that once the task is scheduled at nth minute , I want the timer to pause as it will take more than one minute to complete.

I want to know , is there a way to cancel the timer when job is scheduled and reschedule when the job is done.

I tried using timer.cancel but it throws IllegalState exception.

Comment: You might want to look at quartz scheduler java...http://quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Are you using classic Timer/TimerTask or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?  (latter one is the preferred way of scheduling tasks nowadays)